# How to use a query in another query?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

If I want to use a query in another query what should I use :

- reference
- duplicate

and what's the difference between the 2 functions ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you see "related" but the other two show up if you right-click a query in the Power Query Editor.

[image: Pop up]

**Duplicate** is like copy and pasting a query. It creates another query with all of the same steps and code. It's independent and modifying one query doesn't affect the other.

**Reference** does not reproduce the query. The new query starts exactly where the referenced query ended and is therefore dependent on it. If you change the referenced query, then the new query is affected too.

Answer (score 0):

**Duplicate** creates a new copy with all the existing steps. The new copy will be isolated from the original query. You can make changes in the original or the new query, and they will NOT affect each other.

**Reference**, on the other hand, is a new copy with only one single step: getting data from the original query.

Comment: You are correct, but warning: It uses extra work if it is not a `dataflow`.  (Unless you set them up by uncheck-ing `query enable load`) . Details on why it's duplicate work is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/power-query-referenced-queries